# PHP Using Stripos and array_push

Tags: php, arrays, stripos

I'm new in stackoverflow. But I need help, look, i'm making a function that extract multiple words from a string. The problem is that it returns number.
I tried it with another $cuerpo, but it doesn´t work, it returned me 4.
Please help me. Thanks a lot.
Here's my code.

```
<?php
$cuerpo = " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec viverra metus in turpis scelerisque, a mollis purus egestas. Quisque viverra rhoncus nisi, at semper nisi lobortis eu. Ut porttitor mattis orci. Quisque laoreet interdum libero, ut tristique velit tempus nec. Donec id auctor mi. Proin in quam ligula. Aenean suscipit pharetra pharetra.";
function extrae_cadenas($arraystring, $cuerpodos) {
    $total = array();
    $arr = array();
    $arraynum = count($arraystring);
    $cont = 0;
    $contador_substr = 1;
    if(is_array($arraystring))
    {
        foreach($arraystring as $current)
        {
            $cont=$cont+1;
            $on=strlen($current);
            if($cont == $arraynum)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if($contador_substr > 1)
                {
                    $pos = $pos + $on;
                }
                else
                {
                    $pos = stripos($cuerpodos,$current);
                }
                if($pos==true)
                {
                    $a = substr($cuerpo,$pos,30);
                    $salidas = array_push($total,$a);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            $contador_substr = $contador_substr + 1;
        }
        if($salidas == "")
        {
            $salida = "No se encontraron las palabras";
        }
        else
        {
            $salida = $salidas;
        }
        return $salida;
    }
    else
    {
        return "No";
    }
}
print_r(extrae_cadenas(array("_lorem_","_ipsum_"),str_replace(" ","_",str_replace("\n","_",$cuerpo))));
?>
```

Comment: Please consider indenting your code properly, it is very difficult to read as it is.

Comment: RTFM: http://stripos. You're using it wrong. It does not return 'true'. It returns an `int` if the value is found (including 0 if the value is at the start of the string), or a boolean FALSE if it's not found.

Comment: I tried to change this:
if($pos==false)
                {
                }
                else
                {

                    $a = substr($cuerpo,$pos,30);
                    $salidas = array_push($total,$a);
                }

But nothing happens, it returned me again 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from these lines:

```
$salidas = array_push($total,$a);

// ........

if($salidas == "") {
    $salida = "No se encontraron las palabras";
} else {
    $salida = $salidas;
}
return $salida;
```

The function [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) returns the number of elements in the array, so it returns 1 if you have one element and so on...

I guess you have to return `$total` instead, like:

```
if($salidas == "") {
    $salida = "No se encontraron las palabras";
} else {
    $salida = $total;
}
```

And, also, you have to declare `$cuerpo` as a global variable inside the function.